# Getting a value from alert box

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem extracting a value from an alert box. Is there a way to get a value from a predefined alert box, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Sasa +1 for navigating to the right way of asking a question and not downvote  a new user  :-)

Answer (score 4):

You should probably consider using `prompt` instead of `alert`. JavaScript has 3 types of user dialogs: `alert`, `confirm`, and `prompt`.

Using `prompt` you can get text input from the user. Have a look at the documentation on [`Window.prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt).

As an example, consider the various usages in the code below:

```js
var name = prompt("prompt - Please enter your name")

alert("alert - Hello, " + name + "! You can't enter text here!");

var clickedOk = confirm("confirm - Do you understand now?");
```